# What is the sequence of execution of angularjs components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularJS. I am trying to debug a full-fledged angularjs app. I am totally confused as it contains lot of directives, providers, filters and controllers. Moreover, It also uses lazyloading using oclazyload. Individually, I know about directives, providers, filters and controllers and routing. But when all put together, I am totally confused. I have tried searching angularjs docs, but couldn't find any good reference.

Can you please explain me what's the flow of execution/sequence of things happens in the angularjs app ? In other words, in which order angularjs components such as controllers, directives, filters, providers, services will be processed, and how many times ?

I beg your pardon, for may be such simple question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The controllers are initialized when you reference them in your html files.
Services/directives will be initialized when calling them, when services will be initialized once per app and directives each time you use one.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the sequence ? Moreover, what's difference between registering, initializing and instantiating and when each one of them takes place ?

Comment: Registering is writing `app.controller(...)` and it happens when you reference your Javascript files in `index.html`, initializing as mentioned when your html references that control so when that html is loaded.